# Unable to login ECR web page and show error message

Tags: amazon-ecr

Could you check why user kcizek is not able to login to either hub.tess.io nor ecr? This is first time login but it should work with corp and PIN + Yubi. Login works for me just fine.

I am unable to access https://ecr.vip.ebayc3.com/repository/
When I log in, I am faced with this. The ‘contact us’ link doesn’t have any contact information, so I’m trying here. Any ideas? Thanks.
Potentially relevant background: this is my first time attempting to get access.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VI5x.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's found the email info is absent in user account.

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+
| Field     | Value                            |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
| domain_id | default                          |
| email     |                                  |
| enabled   | True                             |
| id        | e69fe5b9d9384b338b3c397c7c84e33f |
| name      | kcizek                           |
+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

Solution is to contact Tess oncall to add email info.

Related Command

```
openstack user set kcizek  --email kcizek@ebay.com
```